# Hide content if function condition is met (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a registration form, based on Contact Form 7, that I'd like to hide when the number of submissions has reached 600. I'm using Contact Form Database (CFDB) to store the submitted data and it's possible to generate a shortcode to output the number of submissions (it's called "cfdb-count" below).

I'm using Wordpress.

This is what I've tried but it's not working:

```
<?php
$sumregistrations = " . do_shortcode('[cfdb-count form="The reg form"]') . ";
if ($sumregistrations > 600 ){
           // Hide the form
           }else {
           // Show the form 
           }
?>
```

EDIT: Here is a working solution for this problem:

```
<?php require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/CFDBFormIterator.php');
$exp = new CFDBFormIterator();
$exp->export('NAME OF THE FORM', array('show' => 'submit_time', 'trans' => 'CountField(submit_time)'));
$count = 0;
while ($row = $exp->nextRow()) {
    $count = $row['submit_time'];
}
if ($count > 600 ): ?>
    //Content to show if number of submissions are greater than 600.
<?php else : ?>
    //Content to show if number of submissions are less than 600.
    //For example, show the form <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="112" title="NAME OF THE FORM"]'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You should be getting a parse error from this `$sumregistrations = " . do_shortcode('[cfdb-count form="The reg form"]') . ";` you need to escape the inner double quotes `$sumregistrations = " . do_shortcode('[cfdb-count form=\"The reg form\"]') . ";` try that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for your answer. I tried that but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sumregistrations = do_shortcode('[cfdb-count form="The reg form"]');
```

You've created a weird attempt at concatenating a string when you don't really need to. If that shortcode returns a number, you don't need to add anything else to it.

EDIT:

After perusing the [repository for this plugin](https://github.com/mdsimpson/contact-form-7-to-database-extension), this shortcode outputs a string wrapped in HTML. Therefore, you cannot use it to compare against 600, as it will always return false. You should get the count value directly from the db table.

Comment: I tried what you suggested above. I also tried that along with @Fred-ii-'s suggestion without any luck. I have now tested this code to see if it works, but even this doesn't work...What is causing the error with this code?

    `<?php
    $sumregistrations = 3;
    if ($sumregistrations > 3 ){
           Hide the form
           }elseif {
           Show the form 
           }
    ; ?>`

Comment: Well what is your error? What is it doing/not doing? You have to be more specific...

Comment: Do this after the line above: `var_dump($sumregistrations);` and post the output here

Comment: I used Execute PHP Online at www.tutorialspoint.com and this is the output: 
`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'the' (T_STRING) in /home/cg/root/main.php on line 6`

Comment: Ok, so using a function like this with that shortcode will never work?
Can you give some advice on how to get the count value directly from the db table? Or do you mean I have to get it manually?

Comment: @Marcus you'll need to see if CFDB or CF7 provides a way to access that raw data, otherwise you need to find where it's stored in the db and run your own query.